# Open layers: coordinates with comma in decimal format

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, decimalformat

I'm rendering the mouse position like so:

```
map.addControl(new ol.control.MousePosition({
  coordinateFormat: function (coordinate) {
    return ol.coordinate.format(
      coordinate, 
      'E {x}  N {y} (' + projectionTitle + ')', 3
    ).replaceAll( '\.', ',' );
  }
}));
```

The part with `replaceAll` works fine, but is hacky and I'd like to use a "recommended" way of formating coordinates in OL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If your users are all in the same country your solution is adequate.  If you want to support individual users local number format in many countries you could use `toLocaleString` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#using_options

```
map.addControl(new ol.control.MousePosition({
  coordinateFormat: function (coordinate) {
    const options = {minimumFractionDigits: 3, maximumFractionDigits: 3}
    return 'E ' + coordinate[0].toLocaleString(undefined, options) +
      '  N ' + coordinate[1].toLocaleString(undefined, options) +
      ' (' + projectionTitle + ')';
  }
}));
```

Comment: good to know. In my case the commas are strongly required independently on locale